# Trying to calculate difference between two dates using time.h library

Tags: c++, c, time, time.h

I'm trying to calculate the exact difference between two dates i give using my own Date struct, i'm now testing the functions which returns the difference:

```
Date dateDifference(Date a, Date b){
    time_t rawtime,timeA,timeB;
    struct tm* tA,*tB;
    double difference;

    time(&rawtime);
    tA = tB = localtime(&rawtime);

    tA->tm_mday = 20;
    tA->tm_mon = 1;
    tA->tm_year = 115;

    tB->tm_mday = 3;
    tB->tm_mon = 10;
    tB->tm_year = 89;

    timeA = mktime(tA);
    timeB = mktime(tB);

    difference = difftime(timeA, timeB);
}
```

As you can see i gave some manual numbers into the two 'tm' structs to test it.
When i debug i get the exact same value in both "timeA" and "timeB".
I'm not really familiar with the time.h functions and therefore i'm doing it using knowledge i find on the web, and this is the best i succeeded achieving.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The two problems you have are:

`localtime()` returns a pointer to a structure in its own static memory. You should copy the structure before you call `localtime()` again.

You did't allocate any memory for the two `tm` structures - I have changed them from pointers to simple structures.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t timeA, timeB;
    struct tm tA, tB, *tptr;
    double difference;

    time(&timeA);
    time(&timeB);
    tptr = localtime(&timeA);
    tA = *tptr;
    tptr = localtime(&timeB);
    tB = *tptr;

    tA.tm_mday = 20;
    tA.tm_mon = 1;
    tA.tm_year = 115;

    tB.tm_mday = 3;
    tB.tm_mon = 10;
    tB.tm_year = 89;

    timeA = mktime(&tA);
    timeB = mktime(&tB);

    difference = difftime(timeA, timeB);
    printf ("Difference is %.0f seconds\n", difference);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Difference is 798336000 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

One could think, that this is caused by

```
tA = tB = localtime(&rawtime);
```

However, this is only half of the truth, because separating this into

```
tA = localtime(&rawtime);
tB = localtime(&rawtime);
```

leads also to the result, that `tA` and `tB` both point to the same address. This is stated in the [manpage of localtime (man 3 localtime)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime): "The return value points to a statically allocated string which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions."

Therefore, you have to copy one of the two to a newly allocated `struct tm`.

Answer (score 1):

Both `tA` and `tB` should used a `struct tm`and not a pointer as in `struct tm *`.  That way they each have their own memory to manipulate.

The original code used pointers to the same memory location.  So changing one also changed the other.

```
Date dateDifference(Date a, Date b){
    time_t rawtime,timeA,timeB;
    // struct tm* tA,*tB;
    struct tm tA, tB;
    double difference;

    time(&rawtime);
    // tA = tB = localtime(&rawtime);
    tA = tB = *localtime(&rawtime);

    tA.tm_mday = 20;
    tA.tm_mon = 1;
    tA.tm_year = 115;

    tB.tm_mday = 3;
    tB.tm_mon = 10;
    tB.tm_year = 89;

    timeA = mktime(&tA);
    timeB = mktime(&tB);

    difference = difftime(timeA, timeB);
    ...
}
```

Code likely has another subtle problem.  Assuming the following is today's day, there is an off-by-1 error

```
    tA.tm_mday = 20;
    // tA.tm_mon = 1;
    tA.tm_mon = 1 - 1;  // months since January
    tA.tm_year = 115;   // years since 1900
```